# What 11-32 10 speed cassettes will work with Shimano 105 5700 freehub?

Tags: cassette, compatibility, freehub

I have a Shimano 105 5700 10 speed hub, currently with a 12-27 cassette. I want to go to an 11-32 cassette. There is no 5700 10 speed cassette that goes beyond the 12-27. There is an Ultegra 11-32 (6700?), but i'm looking for a cheaper option. I have seen a Deore XT 10 speed 11-32 cassette, will that work? I am using a 105 long cage rear derailleur (5700-GS).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are Tiagra 10 speed 11/32 and 11/34 cassettes available according to the [Shimano page](http://bike.shimano.com/content/sac-bike/en/home/road/drivetrain/cassettes0/cs-hg500-10.html).  Coming from the road group, they will work.